# Timakeystore.jar not found

Tags: java, android, keystore

I have been debugging in Android Studio with a Samsung SM-T280and noticed these warnings every time there is access over the network:

```
W/: Unable to open '/system/framework/timakeystore.jar': No such file or 
directory
W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/timakeystore.jar': I/O 
Error
```

After some searching for timakeystore.jar I came across https://seap.samsung.com/sdk/knox-standard-android/ and appears to be some keystore as the name implies.

I have been reading, and without any success cannot find any reference to timakeystore.jar and how to get it or even disable this feature.

Does any one here have any expertise with this and maybe shed some light on where to get this jar file or how to disable this feature?

Regards.

Comment: https://github.com/fossasia/phimpme-android/issues/1032

Comment: google it?????? I did..

Comment: @antoniossss i did try googleing that error string, the file name and other variations with and without quotes and nothing came up other than the samsung link I posted. Search quite a few articles and found nothing. That is why I poated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm yet to figure out what was the real cause of the problem but it seems that most people who experience this problem use Samsung devices to test android apps.

For my case, I had to Invalidate Cache in Intellij and Restart (the option is under "File" menu), also disconnect and restart my Samsung device. It solved the problem.

This is just a work around and not a permanent solution, probably I will encounter the same problem again and forced to do the same thing.